# Database-safe Date/Time String?

Tags: database, datetime, format

Which format of a date/time string would be considered cross-platform, cross-database, universal safe?

Would this `YYYY-MMM-DD HH:MM:SS` be considered safe to use in MySQL, SQLite 2 & 3, MsSQL and other common databases?

How about something like `2010-Jul-12 12:00:00pm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pick a defined standard, such as the [ISO standard for date and times](http://www.iso.org/iso/date_and_time_format). It's pretty universal and easy to use and understand, and as a defined standard you can just say "all datetimes must be ISO 8601" and be done with it. No worries about locale or cultural confusion.

Comment: That ISO link doesn't work any more, they've changed the site - LOL. This one may be applicable: http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=40874 (i liked the first URL much better)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever possible, you should pass and store dates using a real date/time type. Strings will often cause problems if the culture changes (and probably on different database platforms, too).

If your language or database library allows you to use strongly typed parameters in your database queries, that would be the safest way to do this. If you use a date/time type for your columns and pass the values using your language's date/time type, the library will make sure that your dates are handled correctly.

Comment: is right. The safe and robust approach is to use a real date/time type, which encodes the time coordinate as the number of elapsed units since an epoch. This is how dates are typically stored on computers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29

Answer (score 0):

You don't have really have a "safe" DateTime. It all depends on Cultures,
UK is DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:ss
US is MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:ss or whatever not entirely sure if it actually is or not but nontheless it is different.

I would just stick with your "culture", and be consistent throughout you code so furture developers can easilly read you code with figuring out what kind of crazy convention you have for your data and time.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ISO standard - YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]

Or as an alternative YYYYMMDD.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx