# Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL - date type conversion issue

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

I am migrating my database from MySQL to MSSQL with SSMA tool.
Here a value of date type column in MySQL for e.g.
'2015-08-05' is convert into '05-Aug-15' in MSSQL instead of '2015-08-05' value.
I need a same value '2015-08-05' in MSSQL instead of '05-Aug-15'.                 how to achive this ?. I am using MSSQL 2014 version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database-safe Date/Time String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494981/database-safe-date-time-string)

Comment: [Dates are not saved with display format in mssql](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30033028/3094533). The string representation you see is just that, a string representation. Inside, sql server keeps datetime values as two 4 bytes integers.